# Bitmap Image Resizing

Tags: android, bitmap, resize

I have a problem that occurs when I click an image using Intent and launch Android Camera. The image that I get through **Intent data** carries information of resized Bitmap image. Maybe I have a wrong understanding, but please suggest what can I do to correct it. The ImageView displays the same image I clicked but a very blurrred one

Here is the underlying code:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
InputStream stream= null;
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            try{
                //stream= getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Bundle extras= data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageHolder.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use bitmap.createScaledBitmap();

Comment: why don't use uri instead of bitmap ?

Answer (score 0):

```
       try{
            //stream= getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            Bundle extras= data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            //set value Width=200, Height=200
            Bitmap resizedimg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Width, Height, true);

            imageHolder.setImageBitmap(resizedimg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The image is still blurred even after using bitmap.createScaledBitmap

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should pass a uri to Camera, and get image from it when ActivityResult instead of bitmap

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static int CAMERA_TAKE_PIC =1;
    Uri outPutfileUri;
    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    }


    public void CameraClick(View v) {

        Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "Photo.jpg");
        outPutfileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutfileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_TAKE_PIC);
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_TAKE_PIC && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {

            String uri = outPutfileUri.toString();
            Log.e("uri-:", uri);
            Toast.makeText(this, outPutfileUri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri);
           // mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uri));   OR drawable make image strechable so try bleow also

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), outPutfileUri);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                mImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
}

}
```

i think the image is blurred because the intent data contains only the `thumbnail` of the image.you can save the image on the internal/external storage and then acquire it.

Answer (score 0):

The image is probably blurred because the intent data contains only the thumbnail of the image. You must save the image on the internal/external storage and then acquire it.Also your question should be how to get full size image from camera.
Go through this doc https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html.

This is how it should be done

```
Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File dir=
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

output=new File(dir, "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
```

Refrence can be found in this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32121829/3111083