# Getting Blur image in onActivityResult() and How to get good quality Captured image in onActivityResult()

Tags: java, android

After clicking camera, if RESULT is OK then it should ask user to enter the file name in an alert dialogue and store it in particular folder.
But the image is getting blur.

```
 if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent in = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(in, 0);
    }}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        SaveImage(imageBitmap);
    }}


public void SaveImage(Bitmap showedImgae){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CaptureActivity.this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.filenamepomfret, null);
    EditText pomname=view1.findViewById(R.id.pomname);
    pomname.setText(getFileName());
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("Enter File Name");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", (dialog, which) -> {

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) ->
            dialog.dismiss()
    );
    builder.setView(view1);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Boolean wantToCloseDialog = (pomname.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (!wantToCloseDialog) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            File myfolder = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)));
            myfolder.mkdirs();
            String fname = pomname.getText().toString();
            File imageFile = new File(myfolder, fname);
            if (imageFile.exists()) imageFile.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                showedImgae.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                Toast.makeText(CaptureActivity.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                  Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
              mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            }

        }  });
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        dialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a blurry image appear in a simple android camera app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121729/why-does-a-blurry-image-appear-in-a-simple-android-camera-app)

Comment: if i use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT wont return anything in onActivityResult  and can not pass image name through alert dialog

Comment: "if i use MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT wont return anything in onActivityResult" – That's to be expected. You don't need anything returned, because you will know exactly where the image is stored. "can not pass image name through alert dialog" – You can still ask the user for a filename, but you'd either have to do it before starting the `Intent`, or use a temp file and rename/move it afterward. If you don't want to do that, then you'll likely have to handle the camera directly yourself.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to get clarity image  by using bitmap ?

Comment: If you're asking if the full-res image can be passed to you on the `Intent` in `onActivityResult()`, the answer is no. It will be too big to put on an `Intent`. That's the reason for the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` option.

Answer (score 0):

before onCreate method:

```
private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 1001;
Uri image_uri
```

Call this method to pick image from camera:

```
public void pickCamera() {
    //take image from default camera
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From Camera");
    image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);
}
```

now on activity result:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                //set image to image view
                mImageView.setImageURI(image_uri);
            }
        }

    }
```